# How do I pull compile_commands.json from a subdirectory?

Tags: neovim

I've got a c++ cmake project. I've created a subdirectory `work` in the main directory that I'm using for compilation. When I compile the project I cd into `work` and do `cmake .. && make`. This way, compiler files do not pollute the main directory. `work` is also the directory, where `compile_commands.json` is generated, and I use that for coc syntax highlighting.

As long as it's in the subdirectory, coc can't find it, therefore, I created a softlink in the main directory that leads to the file. This works, and another solution would be adding a command to `CMakeLists.txt` that would copy the file to the main directory, but I keep wondering if there is a better way to do it. And with a better way, I mean, something like creating `.vimrc` in the main directory and writing in it commands that coc could use to find the file.

So far, I have found vim command that allows me to move into that direction, `set exrc` will load local `.vimrc` files

One thing I've tried is putting

```
" setting with vim-lsp
if executable('ccls')
   au User lsp_setup call lsp#register_server({
      \ 'name': 'ccls',
      \ 'cmd': {server_info->['ccls']},
      \ 'root_uri': {server_info->lsp#utils#path_to_uri(
      \   lsp#utils#find_nearest_parent_file_directory(
      \     lsp#utils#get_buffer_path(), ['.ccls', 'compile_commands.json', '.git/', 'work/compile_commands.json' ]))},
      \ 'initialization_options': {
      \   'highlight': { 'lsRanges' : v:true },
      \   'cache': {'directory': stdpath('cache') . '/ccls' },
      \ },
      \ 'whitelist': ['c', 'cpp', 'objc', 'objcpp', 'cc'],
      \ })
endif
```

into the local .vimrc file, but that didn't work

What command should I put into the .vimrc located in the main directory to tell coc plugin to look for `./work/compile_commands.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Build your project with clang++
Add -MJ to compile command -
clang++ -MJ a.o.json -Wall -std=c++11 -o a.o -c a.cpp

And combine *.o.json to compile_commands.json file using -

find ./work -name '*.o.json' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -e '1s/^/[\n/' -e '$s/,$/\n]/' > ./work/compile_commands.json